# Uncaught type error: "(function call) is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, methods, constructor

I'm trying to call a function via a method, but I'm receiving an error stating that it's "not a function". I used to have the JS code in my HTML, but after I moved it to its current location (that utilizes a class and constructor) the functionality stopped working. As such, I think there's something I'm missing related to classes/constructors, but I'm not sure what.

**index.js:**

```
import calendarComponent from "./SiteAssets/scripts/calendar";

let isAdmin;

async function initComponents() {
  isAdmin = await isAdminMember();
  const { globalData, mmUser } = await globalInitProm(isAdmin);

  const calendar = new calendarComponent(globalData, mmUser);
  calendar.initRoutes();

  document.getElementById('getFile').addEventListener('change', calendar.handleFileSelect, false); // ----- click event ----- //

}

initComponents();
```

---

**calendar.js:**

```
export default class {
  constructor(globalData, mmUser) {
    this.globalData = globalData;
    this.isAdmin = mmUser.IsAdmin;
    this.calendar = null;
  }

  initRoutes() {}

  handleFileSelect(evt) {
    console.log("handleFileSelect fired"); // works
    let files = evt.target.files;

    if (files.length > 0) {
      this.parseAndUploadFile(files[0]); // "Uncaught TypeError: this.parseAndUploadFile is not a function"
    }
  }

  parseAndUploadFile(file) {
    console.log("trying to load excel file");
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      // etc
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue is because `this` refers to the `input` element. I assume you're expecting it to refer to the outer scope containing your function definitions?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, either use `bind` or use `delegate callback`.

```
export default class {
  constructor(globalData, mmUser) {
    this.globalData = globalData;
    this.isAdmin = mmUser.IsAdmin;
    this.calendar = null;
    this.handleFileSelect = this.handleFileSelect.bind(this) // bind this here
  }
  // rest od the code

}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.